# Programming error when inserting variables from CSV to SQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, csv

I'm web scraping data and trying to place it into my table in my SQL. This error keeps appearing even after I changed what i originally thought was wrong

```
ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type, bathrooms, bedrooms)VALUES('495000', '119 The Dargan Building, Heuston Sou' at line 1
```

originally it was that my database table didn't have enough characters for the variable address it was set only to 50 but I've now changed that to 250 but the same error has appeared. This is the code now running:

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
#creating csv file
with open ('daftdata.csv','w') as file:

    for row in all_var:
        writer.writerow(row)
    file.close      

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='123',
database='123')
#prepare cursor
cursor = mydb.cursor()
with open("daftdata.csv", "r") as infh:
    reader =csv.reader(infh)
#csv_data = csv.reader('daftdata.csv')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dafttable(price, address, house type, bathrooms, bedrooms)VALUES(%s, %s, %s,%s,%s)",row)

#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For columns that are a `char` type the value should be surrounded by quotes. Looking at the SQL, this should apply to the address column, so the query should be modified to have single quotes around the value.

Also column names with spaces in them need to be surrounded with back ticks or quotes. This applies to the `house type` column. Some database engines also support square brackets around column names with whitespace.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dafttable(price, address, `house type`, bathrooms, bedrooms)VALUES(%s, '%s', %s, %s, %s)",row)
```

Comment: if you just remove the word house, so you're left with "type", it gets rid of that error but if you keep [house type] it keeps the same error!